# Python: How to iterate each element of a dict in a for loop when for one key there are n value

Tags: python

I'm really new about python and now I'm approaching about the fantastic world of the `dict`.
I looked for the solution, but I didn't find.
My doubt is (actually I don't know if this is a conceptual error!):

```
first_list = ['a','b','c']
second_list = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']

dict_complete = dict.fromkeys(first_list,second_list)
print(dict_complete )
{'a': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'], 'b': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'], 'c': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']}

for i, j in dict_complete.items(): 
    print(i, j)
a ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
b ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
c ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
```

I don't want the above iteration, but this below:

```
      for i, j in dict_complete.items():
         print(i, j)
'a' '1'
'a' '2'
'a' '3'
'a' '4'
```

Probably my question might make someone smile, but if you link me documentations or an answer will be a big gift for me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A nested `for` loop.

Comment: A dictionary can't have multiple values with the same key, so what you ask for is impossible.

Comment: OP seems to only be concerned with printing/displaying the information. I see nothing in their post that suggests they want actual key-value pairs `'a' '1'`, `'a' '2'`, etc.

Comment: I was as I supposed. 
It is a conceptual error.
Because in python there is a concept about key:value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a nested loop.

```
first_list = ['a','b','c']
second_list = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']

dict_complete = dict.fromkeys(first_list,second_list)
print(dict_complete )
{'a': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'], 'b': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'], 'c': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']}

for i, j in dict_complete.items():
    for k in j:
        print(i, k)
```

Output:

```
a 1
a 2
a 3
a 4
a 5
a 6
a 7
b 1
b 2
b 3
b 4
b 5
b 6
b 7
c 1
c 2
c 3
c 4
c 5
c 6
c 7
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to iterate over the `n` values:

```py
for key, values in dict_complete.items():
    for value in values:
        print(key, value)
```

Note that using `dict.fromkeys()` with a mutable second argument is likely *not* what you want. Watch what happens when you change the first element of the list at key `'a'`:

```py
In [9]: dict_complete['a'][0] = 99

In [10]: dict_complete
Out[10]:
{'a': [99, '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'],
 'b': [99, '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'],
 'c': [99, '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']}
```

### EDIT

In response to your comment, this is indeed a conceptual error. The keys of a dictionary must be unique. Any duplicate keys which are modified simply overwrite the first. If you want the pairs you describe however, you can use the cartesian product:

```py
first_list = ['a','b','c']
second_list = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']

for letter in first_list:
    for number in second_list:
        print(letter, number)
```

Output:

```py
a 1
a 2
a 3
a 4
a 5
a 6
 .
 .
 .
```

Or if you want to store the pairs,

```py
pairs = []
for letter in first_list:
    for number in second_list:
        pairs.append((letter, number))
```

Output:

```py
[('a', '1'),
 ('a', '2'),
 ('a', '3'),
 ('a', '4'),
 ('a', '5'),
 ('a', '6'),
 ('a', '7'),
     .
     .
     .
```

Even easier with the built-in `itertools.product`:

```py
import itertools

list(itertools.product(first_list, second_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will produce the output shown in the question:

```
first_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
second_list = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']

dict_complete = dict.fromkeys(first_list, second_list)

for k, v in dict_complete.items():
    print('\n'.join(f"'{k}' '{v_}'" for v_ in v[:4]))
    break
```

**Output:**

```
'a' '1'
'a' '2'
'a' '3'
'a' '4'
```